# Knockoutjs sortable with helper:clone, doesn't clone and moves the original item

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, knockout-sortable

Strange issue, I am struggling for couple days. I have a simple knockoutjs sortable page that binds to 2 lists as below.  I would like to move copy an item from list A to B.  I tried passing helper: 'clone' in options as in documentation, but it doesn’t create a copy and moves the original item.

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/a5FL5/13/, that shows the problem.  Try moving item from list A to B, and it moves the original item, and no copy is created.

I haven’t been able to figure out what the issues. Any help is appreciated.

```
    <div class="A">
        <ul data-bind="sortable: { data:stagingList.filteredTodos  , options: {helper: 'clone', connectToSortable: '.okay'}}">
            <li data-bind="text: itemlist">              </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="B">
        <ul data-bind="sortable: { data: dayList.dfilteredTodos }">
            <li class="okay" data-bind="text: itemlist">  </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

Regards
Srini

Comment: Were you able to solve this.. an answer to this would be great, tx